# Can you help me to fix the error in my code?

Tags: python

Write a program allowing user to enter 2 integers, then calculate and print out their sum.

Input: 
A single line consists of 2 integers a and b, separated by a space. a and b are 32-bit integers, and it is guaranteed that their sum also is.

Output:
Print the result following the format "a + b = c" of where c is the sum of a and b.

I have tried to do the code below.

```
# Reads two numbers from input and typecasts them to int using  
# map function 
a, b = map(int, input(4 5).split())
c = a + b
print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, c))
```

I expect the output format is "a + b = c"

Comment: What is `input(4 5)` supposed to do?

Comment: `input("text asking user to put two values")`

Comment: what is the error that needs fixing?

Answer (score 2):

`input` function take one parameter to display the text on console.

`input('enter two numbers')` it will display the `'enter two numbers'` on console, now you enter two number.

Just change your code like this

```
# Reads two numbers from input and typecasts them to int using  
# map function 
a, b = map(int, input('enter two numbers\n').split())
c = a + b
print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, c))
```

You will see output like

```
>>> a, b = map(int, input('enter two numbers\n').split())
enter two numbers
4 5
>>> a
4
>>> b
5
>>> c = a + b
>>> print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, c))
4 + 5 = 9
>>>
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it went like this.   stdin Standard input is empty
 stdout enter two numbers
enter two numbers
 stderr 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 3, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: @MinNguyen , can you paste complete steps and traceback in readable format

Comment: # Reads two numbers from input and typecasts them to int using 
# map function 
a, b = map(int, input('enter two numbers\n').split())
c = a + b
print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, c))

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/45250da2deebf23873cc26b36b9142c3.py", line 3, in <module>
    a, b = map(int, input('enter two numbers\n').split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: @MinNguyen are you running this in any IDE like sublime?. Because I don't think Sublime Text's default console is that it does not support input.
Can you try it with python consloe like `python3 file_path.py`

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function takes one argument, which is the text that is displayed when the user is prompted to enter something.
Your code works fine, the only problem is that you didn't give the function a proper string to work with.

This code will work:

```
a, b = map(int, input("How many candies do they have? ").split())
c = a + b
print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
a, b = map(int, input('Input ').split(' '))
c = a + b
print('{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Comment: According to the question, the desired input is a single line consists of 2 integers a and b, separated by a space.